# Symfony2 - Assetic is not dumping any assets

Tags: symfony, assetic

I have two machines, a development machine running Windows and a production machine running Linux.

The problem I have is that Assetic is not deploying (or finding any) assets in the Linux production machine (neither in `dev` nor in `prod` mode). It was working in the previous deployment attempts, then all of a sudden it stopped without having changed anything in the system or the `config.yml`/`config_prod.yml` file.

The command I am using for dumping:

```
sudo php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

The assets have been defined in the bundles' `public` folders and have been installed beforehand and moved to the `web` folder with:

```
php app/console assets:install --symlink web/assets
```

Comment: Have you executed `assets:install` before the dump and before all have you cleared the cache?

Comment: I have executed `assets:install` before the dump (see question) and I even tried clearing the cache (both by executing the Symfony command as well as by removing the folders manually). Doesn't help. I suspect it is because of something in the symfony2 software which has changed in the recent 3 weeks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I found out that [mthaml-bundle](https://github.com/arnaud-lb/MtHamlBundle) was causing the problem, which I am using in the project. Reverting to an older commit solves the problem, in the meantime I am going to report it.